# proof of succession convergence

Tags: calculus

Prove that the following sequence is convergent and calculate its limit:

$x_1=2$ and 
$x_{n+1} = \sqrt{3 + \frac{x_n^2}{2}}$

I get a limit of 2.4, but by calculating several sequence terms, I can see that it converges to 2.

Comment: I ran 1000 iterations of this and it looks like it converges to ~$2.4495$, so you were probably right the first time.

Comment: Neither is correct, if you plugin $x$ for $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ you get a quadratic equation with the solution $x = \sqrt{6} \approx 2.44948974.\;$ What terms converge to 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $\{x_n\}$ is bounded between $2$ and $\sqrt{6}$ because the bounds are valid for $x_1$ and 
$$x_{n+1}=\sqrt{3 + \frac{x_n^2}{2}} \ge \sqrt{3 + \frac{2^2}{2}} = \sqrt{3 + 2}
\ge \sqrt{2 + 2} = 2
$$
$$x_{n+1}=\sqrt{3 + \frac{x_n^2}{2}} \le 
\sqrt{\frac{6+(\sqrt{6})^2}{2}} =
\sqrt{\frac{6+6}{2}} = \sqrt{6}
$$
Then it is monotone increasing:
$$x_{n+1}^2 = 3 + \frac{x_n^2}{2} = \frac{6+x_n^2}{2} \ge \frac{x_n^2+x_n^2}{2} = x_n^2$$
Therefore it is convergent and the limit $x$ is given by the equation
$$
x=\sqrt{3 + \frac{x^2}{2}} \Rightarrow x^2=3 + \frac{x^2}{2}
\Rightarrow \frac{x^2}{2} = 3
\Rightarrow x^2 = 6
\Rightarrow x = \sqrt{6}$$